# Button that moves box with text - JavaScript Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, button

I have to make this first button called "натисни" make box "кутийка с текст" move to right by 10px when i click the button. Any suggestions ?

Here is the code.

http://jsfiddle.net/08y7rqf5/

```js
// find elements
var banner = $("#banner-message")
var button = $("button")

// handle click and add class
button.on("click", () => {
  banner.toggleClass("alt")
})
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#banner-message {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 300px;
}

button {
  background: #0084ff;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 8px 14px;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #fff;
}

#banner-message.alt {
  background: #0084ff;
  color: #fff;
  margin-top: 40px;
  width: 200px;
}

#banner-message.alt button {
  background: #fff;
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://bootswatch.com/4/flatly/bootstrap.min.css">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


  <script>
    $("button").click(function() {
      $("div").animate({
        left: '250px'
      });
    });
  </script>
</head>
 
<body>
  <!-- задача 1 -->
  <div class="container my-5">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12">
        <ul class="list-group">
          <li class="list-group-item">
            <div class="d-inline-block border p-2 bg-primary text-white" data-margin="10">кутийка с текст</div>
            <input type="button" class="btn btn-info float-right" value="Натисни">
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the `[<>]` snippet editor. Please do not try to bypass restrictions that Stackoverflow sets, like posting a JSFiddle link without code

Comment: No, Please do not remove the snippet. It is part of the question. The link to JSFiddle can go stale

Comment: Thank you so much.Appreciate that.Let me donate you a beer

Answer (score 0):

1. give the div an ID - I use `move`
2. Add CSS `#move { position:relative}`  - you cannot move unless it is position absolute or relative
3. Add the script -(but do not have onclick or similar)

```js
$(function() {
  $('[value="Натисни"]').on("click",function() { 
    const div = $(this).prev(); // or $("#move")
    let pos = Math.round(div.position().left)
    div.css({"left":(pos+10)+"px"}); // or $("#move").css(....)
  })
})
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#banner-message {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 300px;
}

button {
  background: #0084ff;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 8px 14px;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #fff;
}

#banner-message.alt {
  background: #0084ff;
  color: #fff;
  margin-top: 40px;
  width: 200px;
}

#banner-message.alt button {
  background: #fff;
  color: #000;
}

#move { position:relative}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://bootswatch.com/4/flatly/bootstrap.min.css">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 

  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <!-- задача 1 -->
  <div class="container my-5">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12">
        <ul class="list-group">
          <li class="list-group-item">
            <div id="move" class="d-inline-block border p-2 bg-primary text-white" data-margin="10">кутийка с текст</div>
            <input type="button" class="btn btn-info float-right" value="Натисни">
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: just updated the link,can you check it and edit in there ?

Comment: No. Stackoverflow wants the answer and code HERE, not is a link that can go stale or change content

Comment: so what i should do,i tried your code but it's still not moving

Comment: It moves for me here. Did you change to position relative?

Comment: can you just paste your code in pastebin,because im doing something wrong.Thank you

Comment: Try again. Note I am using the value `Натисни` for the button. If you change the value you need to change my script

Comment: can you make it to move on every click not just once ?

Comment: Thank you so much.Appreciate that.Let me donate you a beer

Comment: I don't know what is самогон,but if you want some ракия/rakija i can do it :D

Comment: im sure it's balkan or russian,but i still don't know it,rakija is universal :D

Answer (score -1):

where is your **banner-message** id in your html code ???
And you're using input with type button, not button tag so you cannot use

```
var button = $("button")
```

You need to use

```
var button = $("input[type=button]")
```

But the best way is defined the class for it. Example

```
<input type="button" class="btn btn-info float-right myButtonClass" value="Натисни">
```

and then call it as

```
var button = $(".myButtonClass");
```